# centering jquery-ui button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Strange thing. I center a `div` inside another `div`, and all is fine until the inner `div` is changed to `.button`. Then it is not centered any more.

html:

```
<div style='width:100%;'>
  <div id='bt_click_me' class='button'>Click</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#bt_click_me
{
    width:100px;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

When `bt_click_me` is a regular `div` with just a text, all is fine. when I do `$('.button').button()` then it changes into a nice jquery-ui button, but also moves to the left side of the outer `div`. Any clues?

Comment: is the button class used somewhere else in your css which might confuse the css?

Comment: I think you must have some conflicting CSS. Can you recreate your problem on http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/ or provide a link to your page?

Comment: class **button** definition could be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this has to do with jQuery's CSS altering the behavior of the div by applying the `ui-button` class, which switches the div from a `block` to an `inline-block`, thus making the `margin: 0 auto;` style no longer a valid way to center it (inline elements cannot be centered with `margin`).

Try adding `display: block;` to your style, or add `text-align: center;` to your wrapper div.